# Single File monitoring and read the updated file content in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, job-scheduling, file-watcher

I have single CSV file in shared drive and the data is updated everyday. I have a task scheduler which will monitor the particular Directory, and the scheduler is run everyday and read the updated content.

If two rows are updated in that file, then it will read the first row and store in database then 2nd row will be processed. Even if I get any exception in 1st row, also 2nd row should be processed.

I know there is java watcher service to monitor but i have scheduler already. Is there any other way or how I will integrate the watcher service with spring?

Comment: You can use Spring Integration to watch for a file then kick off your batch job.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want a way to scheduled tasks within Spring. In that case why don't you try https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/